# SQL division of 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

As part of an assignment, I have to develop a database for an Airline Company and apply some queries on it.
One of the mentioned queries is to have a rate of occupancy in each flight instance (meaning when a certain flight occurs).
The tables I have are the following:

- Airplanes(serial_number, name, maker, op_start_date, op_end_date, model_name (foreign key)
- Models (name, number_rows, is_narrow, is_wide)
- Narrow_Body (model_name, seats_left, seats_right) - Subclass of Models with 2 seat sectors
- Wide_Body (model_name, seats_left, seats_center, seats_right) - Subclass of Models with 3 seat sectors
- Legs (id, flight_code, order, departure_time, arrival_time, airport_origin, airport_destination, airplane_serial_number (foreign key))
- Leg_Instances (id, flight_code, leg_id, eff_departure_time, eff_arrival_time, date)
- Fly_In (passenger_id, flight_code, leg_instance_id, seat_type, flight_fare, leg_fare) - Gathers the information of a passenger flying in a certain flight and its relevant info

I have other tables, but in this case, only these influence the query in question.

To get the result I applied the following code:

```
DECLARE @number_of_seats TABLE (airplane_serial_number varchar(50), number_seats int);
DECLARE @rate_of_occupancy TABLE (leg_instance varchar(50), airplane_serial_number varchar(50), seats_occupied int, number_seats int, occupancy_rate decimal(5,5));

INSERT INTO @number_of_seats SELECT serial_number, number_rows*(seats_left+seats_center+seats_right) FROM Airplanes JOIN Models ON Airplanes.model_name=Models.name JOIN Wide_Body ON Models.name=Wide_Body.model_name WHERE is_wide='Y'
                         UNION
                         SELECT serial_number, number_rows*(seats_left+seats_right) FROM Airplanes JOIN Models ON Airplanes.model_name=Models.name JOIN Narrow_Body ON Models.name=Narrow_Body.model_name WHERE is_narrow='Y';

INSERT INTO @rate_of_occupancy SELECT Leg_Instances.id, t1.airplane_serial_number, COUNT(passenger_id), number_seats, COUNT(passenger_id)/number_seats
FROM @number_of_seats t1 JOIN Legs ON t1.airplane_serial_number=Legs.airplane_serial_number JOIN Leg_Instances ON Legs.id=leg_id JOIN Fly_In ON Leg_Instances.id=leg_instance_id
GROUP BY Leg_Instances.id, t1.airplane_serial_number, number_seats;

SELECT * 
FROM @rate_of_occupancy
```

Only the last column of rate_of_occupancy i was trying to get the rate of occupied seats in relation to total seats (occupied_seats/total_seats). However the result that was obtained can be found in the following link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJMcv.jpg

Can anyone give me any clarification as to why the rate is 0 in every instance?

Comment: `COUNT(passenger_id)/number_seats`  is probably a division of two integers and you are getting integer division.

Comment: You have a SQL tag and a tag that applies to NoSQL databases. That doesn't make sense. Did you mean just regular aggregation, or am I missing something? Also, if you have a SQL related question, you should tag with the specific RDBMS product (SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL ...) and/or the tag for the SQL dialect implemented by that RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance guys! I do apologize for using the wrong tag, i meant to use one with sql-aggregation.